# How to copy into an uninitialized vector?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm wondering how to go about copying certain elements from a given vector into another one.

```
std::vector<T> vec2;
vec2.reserve(N);
std::copy_if(vec1.begin(),
             vec1.end(),
             vec2.begin(),
             [=](const T& r) {
             return /*something*/
});
```

(At this point `vec1` has a bunch of elements already.)

Or should I use `back_inserter`?

```
std::vector<T> vec2;
vec2.reserve(N);
std::copy_if(vec1.begin(),
             vec1.end(),
             std::back_inserter(vec2),
             [=](const T& r) {
             return /*something*/
});
```

Which of these would work, if either? Also, is the call to reserve necessary?

Comment: You should use `back_inserter`

Comment: Why doesn't the first one work? @IgorTandetnik

Comment: @Dovahkiin It has no elements yet where you are going to copy.

Comment: It exhibits undefined behavior by way of incrementing iterator past the end of the container. `vec2` is empty. I presume `vec1` is not.

Comment: If I use `reserve` beforehand would the first approach work? @IgorTandetnik

Comment: No. `reserve` doesn't change `size()`, only `capacity()`. `resize()` on the other hand would work (assuming `N >= vec1.size()`)

Comment: You can also do `for (auto const& r : vec1) if ( r.something() ) vec2.push_back(r);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is incorrect because `reserve` doesn't add elements to your vector (it only reserves memory which you can't use). `copy_if` requires that the output iterator is valid and it points to the begining of a sequence that's able to hold all the elements you want to copy while your vector after calling `reserve` isn't able to hold the values because it only has raw, uninitialized memory so `begin` effectively returns an iterator to the end. If you copied elements this way the vector wouldn't know those elements are initialized which leads to a lot of problems.
On the other hand, the second solution is fine. `back_inserter` inserts elements to vector (which is more than just allocating memory) so that the vector is aware of what's going on. Note that calling `reserve` doesn't change anything in the aspect of correctness of this code. I mean it could be omited  and the code would work just fine. However, it might be a good idea to leave it there especially if you know how many elements (even if it's just an approximation) you are going to insert. It's going to reduce the number of dynamic allocations which is good for performance.